# Extracting the content of a tag depending its attribute value with beautiful soup

Tags: beautifulsoup, attributes, tags

I have a tree with two tags like this :

`<orgName>This is the full name of the organisation</orgName>`

`<orgName type="acronym">Nickname</orgName>`

To get the full name I can write something like:

`FullName=w.orgName.string (where w is a parent)`

But How can I get "Nickname" without confusion with the full name ?

`FullName=w.orgName(type="acronym")`

does not work...
Thanks for your help

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, add some more details, so that everybody can reproduce your issue. How to create [mcve] - Would be great, thanks

Comment: `FullName=soup.find('orgName', {'type':'acronym'})` should work. But as HedgeHog mentions, you haven't really provided enough to see what the issue is.